# Will Git Force push overwrite/delete tags

Tags: git, tags, push

Will a force push to master overwrite/delete tags created earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you won't lose those tags. They will still point to the same commits.

However do note that if one of those tags points to a commit which has been `--force`'d out of your branch, it will become stale.